# React-Redux app not showing images on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, redux

So I build my app using react-redux and webpack, locally it runs without any problems. When I deploy the app on heroku the images are not displayed, instead I see a broken icon. The path of the images should be fine:

```
const imgPath = '../../style/imgs/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color';
```

I don't get any errors related to the images in the console, they just don't load.

here is my project: https://github.com/jorgeduardos/CryptoPrices

heroku app: https://crypto-waatch.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to import images like so:

```
import someImage from '../../style/imgs/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color'
```

and then `<img  src= { someImage } />`

Comment: mmmm but it works locally, so why would this make a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that while doing `git push`, git converted line endings which leads to broken image data. To avoid it I changed configuration of `.gitattributes` and I added:

`*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.mov binary
*.mp4 binary
*.mp3 binary
*.flv binary
*.fla binary
*.swf binary
*.gz binary
*.zip binary
*.7z binary
*.ttf binary
*.eot binary
*.woff binary
*.pyc binary
*.pdf binary`

It works now :)

It works on local because you serve files from your machine, while Heroku uses files from remote repo where images are broken.